# Share tags between different resource types in cloudformation template

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I'm trying to write a SAM template to have an IoT rule that triggers a Lambda function. The account I'm using requires tagging all resources with a long list of identifiers for billing reasons. These are always the same and it seems a shame to copy them repetitively for each resource. SAM allows for globals shared between one resource type (so every Function can share tags) but I'm not seeing a good way to apply global tags between resource types.

I thought about using a Parameter and trying to reference it, but there are no supported parameter Types that allow for the key/value structure of tags. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html

I'd love to do something like this:

```
Parameters:
  UniversalTags:
    Type: KeyValueObject
    Default:
      - 
        Key: "Name"
        Value: "my name"
      - 
        Key: "Manager"
        Value: "my manager"
      -
        Key: "Market"
        Value: "my market"
       -
        Key: "Engagement Office"
        Value: "location"
      -
        Key: "Email"
        Value: "email@test.com"

Resources:
  IoTProcessingFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      Tags: !Ref UniversalTags

  IoTRule:
    Type: AWS::IoT::TopicRule
    Properties:
      Tags: !Ref UniversalTags
```

Anyone know of any ways to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather put them in the `samconfig.toml` file, like:

```
[default.deploy.parameters]
stack_name = "your-application"
s3_bucket = "your-s3-for-cloudformation-stuff"
s3_prefix = "your-folder-name"
...
tags = "Name=\"my name\" Manager=\"my manager\""
```

That will propagate tags down to all the resources of the stack (including CloudFormation stack itself)

Answer (score -1):

This is something that CloudFormation doesn't do well. Look into [AWS CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/home.html). It allows you to write code that generates CloudFormation. Your CloudFormation will still be repetitive, but you won't need to look at it or maintain it, and you'll be able to describe the Tags only once in CDK